# JSON to CSV with Leading Zeros

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm writing a code to convert JSON to CSV; where i need to retain the leading zeros

I have the file `emp.json` which has numeric values in tag. eg: `000`, `001`, etc along with other tags.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('emp.json')
df.to_csv('test1.csv', index= False)
```

I get the CSV file but the leading zeros in column are removed.

Comment: Use json2csv module:https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv

Comment: @i_th Well, i'll prefer pandas.

Comment: Can you give us sample data for testing please.

Comment: E.g In my Json :  
[{"Code":"001","Description":"Afghanistan"},{"Code":"002","Description":"Albania"},and so on.. 

when i use dtype str or object it takes away the leading zeros.. O/P::   

Code Description
1 Afghanistan
2 Albania

Comment: @Sab You'll have to give us the **exact** small sample code and **exact** small sample data you are using to reproduce the issue.  Everyone using `dtype=str` does not have a problem.

Comment: Well, there's a new piece of information.  It is Excel you are having the issue with.  That hasn't been mentioned before.  The `.csv` file itself is written with leading zeros if `dtype=str`.  Open it with a text editor.  Fixing Excel is a completely different question.  One way is just format the column to write numbers with leading zeros after the file is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a `dtype` argument being `object`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('emp.json',dtype=object)
df.to_csv('test1.csv', index= False)
```

`object` is just a synonym of `str`,

Or you can use `str`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('emp.json',dtype=str)
df.to_csv('test1.csv', index= False)
```

Comment: I tried, it didnt work.. it still takes away the leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But still the same result :( it is removing the leading zeros..

Comment: @Sab funny, let me see.

Comment: @Sab It works for me tho. both `object` and `str` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the data type to be string

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('emp.json',dtype=str)
df.to_csv('test1.csv', index= False)
```

Another way to do it

```
import json
import pandas as pd
jsondata = '[{"Code":"001","Description":"Afghanistan"},{"Code":"002","Description":"Albania"}]'

jdata = json.loads(jsondata)
df = pd.DataFrame(jdata)
print (df.T)
df.to_csv('test1.csv', index= False)
```

Code:https://repl.it/repls/BurdensomeCompassionateCommercialsoftware

Comment: @Sab It works for me. So,  if you find a problem try to check your data and try typ='series'.

Comment: you can use the below input as example. My file is really big.. just giving you an example here.. input ---> [{"Code":"001","Description":"Afghanistan"},{"Code":"002","Description":"Albania"}]

Comment: Thanks for helping. But the code will consider all the data as a string and it writes the data in single cell in excel. But if you just use the df.to_csv it will convert column as "Code" and "Description" as separate cells. the only problem is i cant make the "Code" Column as string, Excel converts them as numeric and ignores the leading zeros.

Comment: You can copy them to the excel easily. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1778-excel-delete-keep-leading-zeros.html

Comment: Moreover, it cosider as pd.DataFrame you can write it easly to excel. `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2')
writer.save()`